# consulta a base de datos con tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

Reformulo la pregunta:

Tengo una base de datos con varias tablas y quiero hacer una consulta donde implico a varias. El problema es que me dice que una de las columnas no la encuentra. No es de la tabla "principal" sino de un de las que enlazo a ella mediante un join. 
La columna que no encuentra es "cr.programmes_level_id", exáctamente cuando pasa por la línea

`$where .= " AND cr.programmes_level_id = ${level_id} ";`

dentro del if (al final).

El error es:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'cr.programmes_level_id' in 'where clause'

Adjunto código:

```
` $join_provinces = ' ( SELECT provinces.id AS id_province, provinces.name AS province_name, provinces.community_id AS community_id, communities.name AS community_name, communities.logo_file AS community_logo_file FROM provinces JOIN communities ON communities.id = provinces.community_id ORDER BY provinces.name ASC ) ';
        $join_programmes = ' ( SELECT DISTINCT programmes_level_id, centre_id FROM centres_requests JOIN centres ON centres.id=centres_requests.centre_id GROUP BY centres_requests.centre_id) ';
        $qb = $this->db->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb
            ->select('c.id AS id', 'c.name AS name', 'cif', 'address', 'zip_code', 'city', 'province_id', 'province_name', 'community_id', 'community_name', 'community_logo_file', 'cm.name AS comunity_manager_name', 'email', 'phone', 'fax', 'underground', 'director_name', 'director_email', 
                    'incorporation_year', 'kids_incorporation_year', 'beda_coordinator_name', 'beda_coordinator_email', 'beda_coordinator_mobile', 
                    'examiner_centre', 'exams_coordinator_name', 'exams_coordinator_email', 'assistants_coordinator_name', 'assistants_coordinator_email', 'extracurricular_coordinator_name', 'extracurricular_coordinator_email', 'observations', 
                    'c.logo_file AS logo_file', 'assistants_number', 'is_cam_bilingual', 'cam_bilingual_year', 'cam_bilingual_year_secondary', 'centre_type', 'beda_kids_coordinator_name', 'beda_kids_coordinator_email', 'community_manager_id', 
                    'educational_levels_candidates', 'educational_levels_candidates_total', 'educational_levels_agreement ' )
            ->from('centres', 'c')
            ->join(
                'c',
                $join_provinces, 
                'provinces_data',
                'provinces_data.id_province = c.province_id' )
            ->join(
                'c',
                'communities',
                'cm',
                'cm.id = c.community_manager_id' )
            ->join(
                'c',
                $join_programmes,
                'cr',
                'cr.centre_id = c.id');

        $search = '%'.$params['search'].'%';
        $search_params = [];
        $where = " logical_delete = ${estado_centro} ";

        if(!empty($level_id)){

           $where .= " AND cr.programmes_level_id = ${level_id} ";
        }
`
```

GRACIAS

Comment: incluye la estructura de las tablas

Comment: y cual es la columna que no encuentra

Comment: No encuentra cr.programmes_level_id

Comment: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cr.programmes_level_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Hola Gema, edita la pregunta para añadir la información que estás poniendo en los comentarios. También sería ideal si pudieras limpiar el código y quitar las líneas comentadas (para quitar "ruido"). Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Aún faltaría algo de información para saber mejor cómo ayudarte: qué framework estás usando (o en qué consisten los `join`), la estructura de las tablas y, si es posible, la sentencia sql generada.

Comment: Disculpad mi ignorancia pero no sé cómo incluir la estructura de las tablas. Estoy utilizando silex

Comment: Revisa que hayas puesto bien el nombre de la tabla, al igual que está en la base de datos

Comment: Eso está revisado y está bien